# changes to css are not retained after postback

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, postback

I have a view that loops through a property in its model and displays a bunch of checkboxes.

These checkboxes are grouped together by their parent and I have a link that shows/hides the div wrapping each group of checkboxes (the javascript collapse function that you see in the code).

Problem is, these checkboxes/groups are bound to the model, and after postback, the model rebuilds itself - and if the end-user had collapsed a group (calls jquery.hide()), it is no longer collapsed.

What is the correct method to persist these css changes in MVC? do I need a hidden field keeping track of their visibility? do I need to update the model object to have a new property that says whether or not to show that group?

coming from webforms... forgive my noobness.

```
     @for (int y = 0; y < Model.SearchControls.Count; y++)
     {
<div style="margin-top: 3px;">
                        <h2 style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="javascript:Collapse(@y);">@Html.Label(Model.SearchControls[y].DisplayText)</h2>
                        </div>

<div id="@string.Format("domainDiv{0}", @y)" style="display:none;">

                            @for (int z = 0; z < Model.SearchControls[y].DomainControl.Domains.Count; z++)
                            {
                                @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.SearchControls[y].DomainControl.Domains[z].Checked)
                                @Html.Label(" " + Model.SearchControls[y].DomainControl.Domains[z].DomainName)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.SearchControls[y].DomainControl.Domains[z].DomainName)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.SearchControls[y].DomainControl.Domains[z].DomainID)
                                <br />
                            }
</div>
```

}

Comment: Are you able to AJAX posts instead? If you use the AJAX POST, your 'state' should be kept.

Comment: I'd rather not use ajax... other options?

Comment: In that case I think having a property in your model is probably the best way to go.

Comment: thank you... I just wasn't sure if that was the best practice in this scenario.

Comment: no prob. If this was helpful, would you consider upticking my comment? Thanks.

Comment: I'd be glad to, I don't see an arrow next to it... I don't think I have the ability to upvote anything with only 8 rep. or how do I do that?